# "Exception is unhandled by user code" even when I explicitly handle the exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

So, in my code, I am throwing an exception manually, using `throw new XYZApplicationException(exceptionID)` if table is not found in the database. That same exception is handled manually in a custom class named XYZApplicationException which inherits from System.Exception.

In the exception handler, I redirect the user to a different page (errordetails.aspx), where I display error details, and what to do in that scenario. This all works fine, but with a catch.

Every time exception is thrown, VS2010 displays error message saying "Exception was unhandled by user code". Then if I click continue, it redirects to errordetails.aspx fine. So, everything works perfectly, apart from that stupid message where I have to click continue.

I have no idea what might have caused the issue. So, any suggestion is welcome.

P.S. This error started occuring after upgrading to .Net 4.0 from .Net 1.1.

Edit:

Apparently, if I disable "Just My Code" in Debugging options in VS, it works fine. So, clearly application is thinking I haven't handled the exception, even though I did. Should I add some kind of declaration, that exception is handled, if my code handles it?

Comment: Dumb question, but are you sure you are differentiating between your own `ApplicationException` and `System.ApplicationException` in your `catch`?

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't wanted to use the name of the application. Actual class is XYZApplicationException where XYZ is application/company name.

Comment: Please check in release mode if that prompting is not happening then Visual studio may be doing additional check in the debug env. Also in the sequence of your calls at some point if you are catching Exception  or XYZApplicationException  then it should be OK.

Comment: I am handling the exception in the XYZApplicationException class constructor itself. That constructor just creates a string based on resource file (a dumb string to display to user). And after that, it is a simple Server.ClearError call, and a redirect to errordetails.aspx.

Comment: Well, it turns out this happens in only Debug mode. Switched to Release, and everything is fine. weird, but who cares, as long as it works. If it was up to me, I will probably nuke the whole application anyway, cuz this throwing exception manually is dumbest way to handle database errors.